# Explicit passing initial value as undefined in array reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I was testing few scenarios with array reduce function.

```
[1,2].reduce(function(initial ,  val){

        return initial+val;
    } ,1)
    // returns 4 as expected


[1,2].reduce(function(initial ,  val){

    return initial+val;
})
// returns 3
```

But explicitly passing `undefined` as initial value

```
[1,2].reduce(function(initial ,  val){

    return initial+val;
}, undefined)
// returns NaN.
```

It appears unusual to me.

Comment: checkout the syntax of array reduce ```arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])``` where initial value is used as the first argument to the first call of the callback.

Comment: I have seen that . In first case it ignores the initial undefined however in second case it returns NaN. Let me add one more example for better clarity

Comment: it's because you are trying to add ```undefined``` with a number try ```[1,2].reduce(function(initial ,  val){
    initial = initial?initial:0
    return initial+val;
}, undefined)```

Comment: Your example is working but the confusion what is the actual difference between the second and third case as in both the cases initial has undefined.

Comment: it's an optional parameter right ??

Comment: this is an optional parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explaination [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

> **Note**: If `initialValue` isn't provided, reduce will execute the callback function starting at index 1, skipping the first index. If `initialValue` is provided, it will start at index 0.

So your second case is similar to this:

```
[2].reduce(function(initial, val){
    return initial+val;
}, 1)
```